# Drop rows when rows have same values in different order

Tags: python, pandas

I would like an efficient way to drop rows from a Pandas dataframe if rows have same values regardless of order

For example, this:

```
1    3
2    5
5    2
1    3
3    1
```

becomes:

```
1    3
5    2
```

Comment: @yatu drop duplicate rows when rows have the same values regardless of ordering

Comment: @Jondiedoop thank you but this does not solve problem

Comment: I noticed, I was too quick with the flagging, excuse me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) the rows of a copy of the dataframe, [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and use the resulting indices to index the dataframe:

```
df_ = df.copy()
df_.values.sort(1)
df = df.loc[df_.drop_duplicates().index, :]
# del df_
```

**Output**

```
    col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     5
```